# JSON array causing extra bracket after POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, post

I am writing a function in freemarker to loops through all checked checkboxes and then re-populate the same response on the same form. Form is in freemarker format and I am using JS to create an individual array for each categories that contains checkboxes. Codes as below:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value="United Kingdom" name="holidays" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value="Australia" name="holidays" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value="United States" name="holidays" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value="Asia" name="holidays" />

<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value="United Kingdom" name="flights" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value="Australia" name="flights" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value="United States" name="flights" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value="Asia" name="flights" />
```

JS:

```
    var extraObjs = {};
    if(validated) {
    $(formRef).find('input[type=text],input[type=password]').each(function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        extraObjs[obj.attr('name')] = obj.val();
    });

    $(formRef).find('input[type=radio]:checked, input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        var obj = $(this);

        if(obj.is('[type="checkbox"]')) {
            if(typeof extraObjs[obj.attr('name')] !== 'object') {
                extraObjs[obj.attr('name')] = [];
            }
            extraObjs[obj.attr('name')].push(obj.val());
        } else {
            extraObjs[obj.attr('name')] = obj.val();
        }

    });
    return extraObjs;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that when the information get sent through POST, results shown are:

```
flights[] ["United Kingdom", "Asia"]
holidays[] ["United Kingdom", "Asia"]
```

It seems that the extra brackets are causing an issue

Comment: What's the purpose of the code?

Comment: Which language are you using on the server side? jQuery will serialize the data as described here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if you get the desired result if you try

```
return JSON.stringify(extraObjs);
```

Comment: This works on all "extraObjs" but how can I target ONLY the checkboxes AND in separate categories for the checkboxes?

Comment: can you please type out the desired JSON categorized output assuming some checkboxes are checked? sometimes looking at how something should turn out in the output helps in reaching it :)